# Why is my SBT intelliJ build not including dependency Jars?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-assembly

My SBT appears to have stopped including dependency Jars. I have been able to do this previously, until I decided to upgrade my intelliJ version, which messed my whole environment. I have since reverted back to the old version, but I still don't see why this is happening.

By build.sbt looks fine, and downloads all the dependencies i ask for. My assebmbly.sbt is also on point.

```
`resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases-scalasbt",  url("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
```

`

I am trying to build a fat jar. When I do a build artifact now, it just builds a jar, but without the dependencies.

I'm new to IntelliJ and SBT, so I am not adept in the way they work. How do I get around this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the latest `sbt-assembly`? You might have to update sbt as well

Comment: hello, a Scala plugin comes with it's own version of SBT

Answer (score 0):

Have we guess which versions you are using. The recent one is sbt.version=0.13.9 set in \project\build.properties".
The resolver statement could be overdone.

Try your build file with the command line. (E.g. In IntelliJ Terminal window, by entering sbt )

Invalidate cache / restart ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to uninstall and Reinstall IntelliJ and deleting all the old configurations. My Jar builds fine now.